# Creating and Accessing a GeometryGroup in CodeBehind

Tags: c#, wpf

i'm new in the StackOverflow Community and please excuse my bad english, i try to imrpove it.

I am using your help for my bachelorthesis and you helped me already a lot, thanks. I am writing a tool to visualize data in wireless networks.

I add a GeometryGroup to my Canvas to connect some of my CustomControls with a line. The line is being updated, when the control is moved etc. I've used the following article: https://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/21/wpf-diagramming-drawing-a-connection-line-between-two-elements-with-mouse/ to make it work.

This is the code i use in my XAML.

```
<Path Name="myPath" Stroke="#FF132FE0" StrokeThickness="1">
                <Path.Data>
                    <GeometryGroup x:Name="connectors"/>
                </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

What i am trying to do is to create my own canvas class and add the GeometryGroup in the code behind. What i tried to do was:

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Path pathGroup= new System.Windows.Shapes.Path(); 
BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();
Brush Brush = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#FF132FE0");
cmp.Stroke = Brush;
cmp.StrokeThickness = 1;
GeometryGroup connectors= new GeometryGroup();
pathGroup.Data=connectors;
```

My Problem is, that it didn't workt as intended. With the XAML implementation i can just use the following:

```
connectors.Children.Add(obj);
```

I try to to sum up my problem. I would like to create with c#-code a GeometryGroup to be able to add and remove lines, whenever i want it.

Thank you =)

Comment: You probably never use `pathGroup` anywhere in your Canvas.

Comment: How am i able to access the children of pathGroup?

There is no such attribute like Children of GetChildren or Data.Children. I dont even know how to Access the Lines i add to the GeometryGroup. Maybe this is my Problem.

Comment: You don't need to "access the children of pathGroup". As before, you would access the Children property of `connectors`. You would however have to *add* `pathGroup` to the Canvas' Children collection.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a derived Canvas with a `connectors` field (similar to the one created from the XAML shown in your question).

The Canvas would draw the connectors by means of an overridden `OnRender` method like shown below.

```
public class CustomCanvas : Canvas
{
    private readonly GeometryGroup connectors = new GeometryGroup();

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        var stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0x13, 0x2F, 0xE0));

        dc.DrawGeometry(null, new Pen(stroke, 1), connectors);

        base.OnRender(dc);
    }
}
```

Some additional code in another method of the derived Canvas class would now add or remove Geometry objects to/from the `Children` collection of the `connectors` object.

---

You might of course also want to declare properties for the connector's Stroke, StrokeThickness, etc.

Comment: It is something i will try to implement! It is much cleaner way to implement this feature.